# jquery Build a checkbox form from 2 json string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, forms

I hit a wall because I just don't know what should I search on at google :( I am actually playing with stackoverflow ask question form for the "Questions that may already have your answer", but can't find anything near

I am trying to build a checkbox form using 2 json string from AJAX result.

The first json string **Category** contains all the `role_id` I only allowed to be used by the form
And the second json string **Roles** contains its user-readable name `roleName`.

So, my HTML *(I am using `twig` template system so, i have `{{ tags }}` )*:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="hidden" name="has_Read[ role.id ]" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="has_Read[ role.id ]" value="1"> role.roleName
</label>
```

I expect that I should loop to every `role_id` in **Category** json string, get each `id` then put it on `has_Read[ role.id ]` then look at **Roles** to extract the `roleName` for the `role_id` to label it in the checkbox form

**Category**

```
[
 {"id":77,"category_id":32,"role_id":1,"has_Read":1},
 {"id":75,"category_id":32,"role_id":99,"has_Read":1}
]
```

**Roles**

```
[
 {"id":99,"roleName":"Administrators"},
 {"id":2,"roleName":"test"},
 {"id":1,"roleName":"Default User"}
]
```

I have very small knowledge of jquery/js aside from the selectors, so I have no idea where to start on building the form, and it seems like its absurd to pass these json strings to php. Can somebody just teach me where to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First transform `roles` into an intermediate hash object, keyed by role id :

```
var roles_ = {};
for(var i=0; roles.length; i++) {
    roles_[roles[i].id] = roles[i];
}
```

Then each of the categories can be given a `.roleName` property, using the `roles_` hash as a lookup :

```
for(var i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
    categories[i].roleName = roles_[categories[i].role_id].roleName;
}
```

Now, the enhanced `categories` array contains all the available data :

```
[
    {"id":77, "category_id":32, "role_id":1, "has_Read":1, "roleName":"Default User"},
    {"id":75, "category_id":32, "role_id":99, "has_Read":1 "roleName":"Administrators"}
]
```

Comment: great trick. I'll check it after I transferred my `$.post()` to `$.ajax()`, because apparently, I cannot store `$.post()` result to global var

Comment: Thank you very much bro!

Comment: No worries. Enjoy.